# Use Octokit to list all commits in all repos on Github using Asp.net Core Razor

Tags: asp.net, github, octokit

I want to be able to show all commits from my Github profile, i did manage to list repos and commits of one repo but can t for all.

[Error msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dnbnz.jpg)
Below is my code :

```
    public IReadOnlyList<Repository> Repositories { get; set; }

    public IReadOnlyList<GitHubCommit> Commits = new List<GitHubCommit>();

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            GitHubName = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
            GitHubLogin = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "urn:github:login")?.Value;
            GitHubUrl = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "urn:github:url")?.Value;
            GitHubAvatar = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "urn:github:avatar")?.Value;

            string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

            var github = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("CommitView"), new InMemoryCredentialStore(new Credentials(accessToken)));

            Repositories = await github.Repository.GetAllForCurrent();

            foreach (var reppo in Repositories)
            {

                var repoCommits = await github.Repository.Commit.GetAll(reppo.Id);
                Commits.Append(repoCommits);

            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: readonly would seem to imply read only.  Just switch to List<> as type?  I've never used IReadOnlyList before, but seems like you'd cast to that if you wanted to use a reference which is read only.

Comment: I have tried but i cant add IReadOnlyList<GitHubCommit> to List<GithubCommit> , and repoCommits is of the type IReadOnlyList<GitHubCommit> and i can not cast it

Comment: yes, change it to a non-read only type so you can add/append it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Octokit.net maintainer here.

The `IReadOnlyList<T>` returned from each collection-based API in Octokit.net is an interface that's part of the .NET Framework which we use to signal that the response returned from the GitHub API is not mutable, and it lacks the mutable APIs like `Add` or `Append`, which is why your sample doesn't compile.

In particular it's this line:

```cs
public IReadOnlyList<GitHubCommit> Commits = new List<GitHubCommit>();
```

`IReadOnlyList<T>` can be enumerated like other collection types, so the quickest way to get your sample working would be to use the `List<T>` APIs instead that support adding a range of elements:

```cs
public List<Repository> Repositories { get; set; }
public List<GitHubCommit> Commits = new List<GitHubCommit>();

public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
  if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
  {
    GitHubName = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Name)?.Value;
    GitHubLogin = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "urn:github:login")?.Value;
    GitHubUrl = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "urn:github:url")?.Value;
    GitHubAvatar = User.FindFirst(c => c.Type == "urn:github:avatar")?.Value;

    string accessToken = await HttpContext.GetTokenAsync("access_token");

    var github = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("CommitView"), new InMemoryCredentialStore(new Credentials(accessToken)));

    var repositories = await github.Repository.GetAllForCurrent();
    Repositories = new List<Repository>(repositories);

    foreach (var repo in Repositories)
    {
      var repoCommits = await github.Repository.Commit.GetAll(repo.Id);
      Commits.AddRange(repoCommits);
    }
  }
}
```